# cmd cannot recognize crawl even it is installed by pip on the cmd window

Tags: python

The path of the Python is correct and added in the path. Why????[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't `crawl` a python package? Don't you need to start Python, then import it?

Comment: I installed. When I import it, there is error